# Laravel 5.3, Can't seem to configure which database to use?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, just trying out some tutorials right now. I'm to the point of trying to connect to a database that I have configured (and am connected to that database using both Sequel Pro and the MySQL command line application). I know my database is working. The name of the database is "auth".

I've also configured Laravel to see this database in the /config/database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'auth'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

This is the code I'm using to connect to the database and pull out the record that matches id=1:

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
public function home() {

    $user = \App\User::find(1);
    echo '<pre>', print_r($user), '</pre>';

    return view('home');
}
}
```

But when I run my application, I see the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

But if I actually create the database "homestead" with a table called "users", the code runs just fine.

Where am I missing a configuration option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with `config/database.php`. `env('DB_DATABASE', 'auth')` this will first check whether `DB_DATABASE` is defined in `.env` file, if not exists only it will use `auth` database.

So you can update the `.env` file or update the config to not to use env variable. Like `'database' => 'auth'`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly... wish my tutorial mentioned that!